# Maximize the length of a sequence of numbers having certain properties

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, integer-division, longest-path

Given a positive integer `n`, I wish to find the longest unique sequence of positive integers, none greater than `n`, such that for every pair of adjacent numbers in the sequence one is an integral multiple of the other.

Given `n=3`, the longest sequence would be:
`(2, 1, 3)` or `(3, 1, 2)`
Because 3 is 1×3, and 2 is 1×2.

Given `n=4`, it would be:
`(2, 4, 1, 3)` or `(3, 1, 2, 4)` or `(3, 1, 4, 2)` or `(4, 2, 1, 3)`
Because 4 is 2×2.

Given `n=5`, it would still be the same because 5 can only pair with 1 but 1 is always full.

Given `n=6`, it can now be `(3, 6, 2, 4, 1, 5)` etc.

I only need one sequence. Here's the one with brute forcing:

```py
n = 6

from itertools import permutations

def check_adjacent(seq):
    for a, b in zip(seq[1:], seq[:-1]):
        min_ = min(a, b)
        max_ = max(a, b)
        if max_ % min_ != 0:
            return False
    return True

def decreaser(n, m):
    for seq in permutations([i for i in range(1, n+1)], m):
        if check_adjacent(seq):
            return seq
    return decreaser(n, m-1)


print(decreaser(n, n))
```

How to design this algorithm since brute forcing would be tragic.

Comment: Why not [3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, ...]? Should an integer only occur at most once? Can 2 be followed by 8 (as 2x2x2)? The rules are not clear.

Comment: Yes every element should be unique, and 2 can be followed by 8 since 8=2*4

Comment: So you can use any coefficient? (4 is neither equal to 2 nor equal to 8). What about 8 and 12, can they be adjacent? (Because 3*8 == 2*12)

Comment: no, it should be multiplied with integer, since 8*1.5=12, 1.5 is not an integer, it shouldn't be adjecent to each other. I think this is my bad that I thought the "multiple relationship" means the bigger one is the integer multiplied to the smaller one.

Comment: Can you show an example with n=6? 6 is the smallest integer who is not a power of a prime number, and I think having examples with 6 would help a lot to understand what you mean by "relations".

Comment: I guess you mean that one of the two should be an integer multiple of the other.

Comment: So this is basically the [longest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) in a graph where vertices are `[1, 2, ..., n]` and there is an edge `(i, j)` iff `i % j == 0 or j % i == 0`. Unfortunately this problem is NP-hard, but there are still algorithms that can work if n is not too huge. (There are also algorithms that are efficients on particular classes of graphs, but I don't think the undirected lattice of divisors is so good here)

Comment: It looks like the longest such sequence has 6 elements (e.g. 3 6 2 4 1 5). Proving (or disproving) this statement would be an interesting exercise in (I suppose) elementary number theory, but it has little to do with programming.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, if there must be `n` elements in the sequence, yes, but it's not clear to me from the title--which I'm having trouble parsing--if that's a requirement (though all the examples have `n` elements). If it's simply required that every element be no greater than `n` the 7-element sequence  `1, 2, 6, 3, 12, 4, 8` (one more than your sequence) works for `n >= 12`. The problem certainly would be more interesting if the latter interpretation applied.

Comment: Starting with 1 is not optimal. You can prepend any unused integer, like 5 here, and 10 can be prepended to that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes if gaps are allowed then one can find longer sequences obviously. The brute force code allows gaps.

Comment: TWTom, must the sequence have `n` elements (as in all you examples) or could there be fewer than `n` (as long as no element exceeds `n`)?

Comment: it could be fewer than n.

Comment: The problem as formulated by @CarySwoveland is known as the *longest path in a divisor graph* problem. (A divisor graph is a graph in a set of natural numbers such that x is connected to y iff x divides y or y divides x). It is not an easy problem. There is some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67296522/finding-the-longest-simple-path-on-the-divisor-graph-using-linear-programming).

Comment: Hey, I found a github doing this by searching divisor graph. Thanks! https://github.com/CarlosLunaMota/Divisor-Graph-Longest-Path